# Group of Socialites.

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a pretty descriptive word for a group of socialites. 
Similar in tone to a roar of lions, rather than usual pride.  A puff of dragons would be another.  It needs to be positive in this instance.

Comment: ...a **party** of socialites. Come on, Jay.

Comment: No no no, @John, you want a ***[cotillion](http://onelook.com/?w=Cotillion&ls=a)*** of socialites.

Comment: @DanBron a ***soiree*** of socialites?

Comment: @JohnClifford a ***do*** of debutantes?

Comment: @DanBron A ***ball*** of bluebloods?

Comment: A *snobbery* of socialites.

Comment: @hotlicks is closer to the money if it were a bit more positive.

Comment: Well, there's always a "snoot full" of socialites.

Comment: I still think if you're looking for a positive fitting term you can't do better than "party". :P Why do you people hate ingenious double meanings? XD

Comment: OK, if you must, there's "twitter of socialites".

Comment: A *social whirl* .

Comment: A coterie of socialites http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coterie

Comment: A clique of socialites http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clique

Comment: A flutter of socialites or a gala of socialites.  In Wikipedia's terms of venery, flutter is applied to butterflies.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal  Same source:  bevy of swans.  Truman Capote referred to his ladies, such as Lee Radziwill, as swans, so, a bevy of socialites.  Not original enough, however.

Comment: I spent 2 years in England and came home with a wonderful word: toff.  Damn, it isn't that grouping word you want thou.  Humm, tank of turtles, murder of crows, den of lions, sterling of toffs?

Comment: If you want Britishisms, *a hooray of Henries* or *a range of sloanes*.

Comment: What about a _gaggle_?

Comment: A klatsch ot socialites.

Comment: A coterie of socialites. Don

Comment: A cotillion of socialites.

Answer (score 1):

Two options: (1) A ***gala of socialites***  or (2) A ***bevy of socialites***

**Gala**, as defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gala)

> a social occasion with special entertainments or performances. "a
>   black-tie gala that begins with a cocktail reception

The OP wants a positive term.  I think gala is appropriate because of the many charity galas socialites organize, which raise large amounts of money for any charity one can think of, from medical research to education to the arts to animal rescue.

From [Daily Mail.com](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3488418/Ren-e-Zellweger-cuts-stylish-figure-charity-gala-hours-sporting-leggings-cap-visit-hair-salon.html)

> Renée Zellweger cuts a stylish figure at charity gala
>
> The 46-year-old wore flared trousers and a chic jacket for the event,
>   which was hosted by Conservation International in Culver City

(Conservation International is an environmental organization.)

(2) ***Bevy of socialites***

According to [Wikipedia, Terms of Venery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal)   there are several terms to refer to a group of swans; **bevy** is one.  (See footnote for "terms of venery".)

Why is a term meaning a group of swans appropriate for a group of socialites?
[Truman Capote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truman_Capote), lifelong friend of [Harper Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harper_Lee), and author of *Breakfast at Tiffany's* and *In Cold Blood* had many socialite friends.  He called these women his **swans**, because of their long-necked elegance and beauty.  See [Vanity Fair, Bye Society](http://www.vanityfair.com/news/1988/04/truman-capote-198804)

> Truman Capote was the darling of an inner circle he called his
>   swans—Babe Paley, Slim Keith, Lee Radziwill, C. Z. Guest, Gloria
>   Guinness, Marella Agnelli.

Any socialite would be thrilled to be placed in this company.

Footnote (Sorry, I don't know how to reduce the font size): from [Wikipedia, Collective Noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun#Terms_of_venery_.28words_for_groups_of_animals.29)

> The tradition of using "terms of venery" or "nouns of assembly,"
>   collective nouns that are specific to certain kinds of animals, stems
>   from an English hunting tradition of the Late Middle Ages......[and]
>   came from France.

Comment: Use <sub><sup>small text<\sup><\sub>

Answer (score 1):

A "functional" definition (roar of lions, puff of dragons) could be a *circle* of socialites, because they all move together in the same social circle.